# How to convert each XML node to Excel row

Tags: xml, excel

I have been trying to convert each xml node to an Excel row to contain all the data including the nodes that have subnodes. I have downloaded XML Editors and tried moving the subnodes out of the parent nodes but it doesn't do it for the whole XML. I have also tried to create and add an XSD but it clears all of my XML contents.

Any help will be much appreciated since I have reached a dead end! This is the XML that I am trying to convert to Excel. I have removed most of the game_action nodes and left a few as an example. So When I load this XML into an Excel, which I can and I do, the Starting_player name, match_player_guid and number are not placed in the same row as the video_time, video_time_start etc etc

```
<game_actions>
<game_action>
  <video_time>159.113</video_time>
  <video_time_start>149.113</video_time_start>
  <video_time_end>169.113</video_time_end>
  <game_time>159.113</game_time>
  <color>0x0000ff</color>
  <starting_player>
    <name>G. Aburjania</name>
    <match_player_guid>ACA150E6-2DA9-CB29-7963-52D514A5B265</match_player_guid>
    <number>8</number>
  </starting_player>
  <ending_player>
    <name>C. Maraggos</name>
    <match_player_guid>532EDB0E-809A-64FD-EAD5-52D514A5C43D</match_player_guid>
    <number>6</number>
  </ending_player>
  <starting_position>
    <x>496</x>
    <y>560</y>
    <zone>6</zone>
  </starting_position>
  <ending_position>
    <x>415</x>
    <y>567</y>
    <zone>6</zone>
  </ending_position>
  <team>
    <name>Anorthosis FC</name>
    <team_guid>bcd1ae4c-4c2d-4c92-978d-6883595d487d</team_guid>
  </team>
  <action>
    <action_id>83</action_id>
    <name>Pass</name>
  </action>
  <direction>right</direction>
  <comments/>
  <uid>39EA2490-FB83-3750-5B65-55D0F5372DE7</uid>
</game_action>
<game_action>
  <video_time>165.866</video_time>
  <video_time_start>155.866</video_time_start>
  <video_time_end>175.866</video_time_end>
  <game_time>165.866</game_time>
  <color>0xcc0000</color>
  <starting_player>
    <name>C. Maraggos</name>
    <match_player_guid>532EDB0E-809A-64FD-EAD5-52D514A5C43D</match_player_guid>
    <number>6</number>
  </starting_player>
  <starting_position>
    <x>402</x>
    <y>585</y>
    <zone>6</zone>
  </starting_position>
  <ending_position>
    <x>675</x>
    <y>44</y>
    <zone>6</zone>
  </ending_position>
  <team>
    <name>Anorthosis FC</name>
    <team_guid>bcd1ae4c-4c2d-4c92-978d-6883595d487d</team_guid>
  </team>
  <action>
    <action_id>88</action_id>
    <name>Attack</name>
  </action>
  <action>
    <action_id>103</action_id>
    <name>Wrong Pass</name>
  </action>
  <direction>right</direction>
  <comments/>
  <uid>C7320CA0-BD4E-2D1B-C4A9-55D14E959346</uid>
</game_action>  </game_actions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 3 options

1. From XML Data Import - button in the Data ribbon.
2. Try using the `MSXML2.DOMDocument` object in VBA.
3. Try using regular expressions (my preference always) e.g. `"<game_action>((?:.|\n)*?)</game_action>"` gets you all game_action tags. Then recursively get the other tags from inside. I made a Add-In with UDF functions [here](http://blog.tkacprow.pl/excel-tools/excel-scrape-html-add/). U can use it to get tag content like this `=GetRegex(CELL_WITH_XML,"<video_time>((?:.|\n)*?)</video_time>";0)` the last argument can be changed to get the next tags